# Java call thirdparty url with parameters in POST from a servlet

Tags: java, url, post, parameters

From my java web application, I want to call a third party site url. Third party url needs some input parameters that they accept only via post.And these inputs are not from the customer who is using my site. And finally third party page will be displayed in an iframe of my site. I am able to do this with a jsp file which will have those inputs are hidden and have onload form submit as below:

```
<body onload="document.form1.submit()">
    <%  
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1
        response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
        response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);
    %>  
<FORM METHOD="post" ACTION="<%= (String)request.getAttribute("thridpartyurl") %>" id=form1 name=form1>
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="rightbox"> 
    <tr>
        <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="<%= (String)request.getAttribute("param1") %>">
                <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="<%= (String)request.getAttribute("param2") %>">

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>    
</form>
</body>
```

But I want to avoid this jsp submission. I am looking for a way to do this without the involvement of JSP. Is there any way to do this in java. From my little search, I understand as  `response.sendRedirect` cannot do a post submission. And `dispatcher.forward(request, response)` cannot use for outside project urls.

Please help.

Regards,

Comment: yes you can use java for this, see this link http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Comment: @Springlearner - I tried mkyong example.output is coming in my jboss server log not in the browser. How can i display the result page in browser?  I am doing this from a servlet. sendget and sendpost are same as mkyong.
public class ExamplePost extends HttpServlet {
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
  try {
   sendGet();
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }
  doPost(request, response);
}
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  {
  try {
   sendPost();
   }
}
}
and finally running ExamplePost to see the thirdparty page

Comment: I did not understand what you want to say]

Comment: @Springlearner - sorry about my way of describing the problem.  in my website , when customer click a button, i want to show this third party page in an iframe or popup. that thirdparty url accepts only post submission. also i need to send some parameter to them. I am looking for a way to do it without jsp. How to call the url is explained in the mkyong page. but after running that inside a servlet with browser, i didnt see the thirdparty page in browser. but the thirdparty page html is printed in the server log. Actually i need the page displayed in browser.

Comment: you want to show 3rd party page in your website/?

Comment: @Springlearner - yes. like advertisements or other services page coming in websites. if  they accept get, then i could do it with response.sendRedirect(url with parameters). but they accept only post. and i am looking for a way to do post and get their page displayed in my site. as mentioned, with the help of jsp, it is easy. but looking for a way to do without jsp and display thirdparty site page in my site iframe.

Answer (score -1):

Below is java code to call any http url.

```
    String url = "thirdparty site url";

    URL obj = new URL(url);

    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    //add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");


    String urlParameters = "param1=value1&param2=value2";

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());
```

Comment: this answer is the direct copy of the link provided at the comment

Comment: Yes it is from the link @SpringLearner

Comment: you should not copy answers from others and post it here. This is called plagiarism and stackoverflow does not allow this